# excel indirect cell reference and index rows

Tags: excel, indexing, transpose

I want to reference the worksheet name and then transpose the totals in row 1 to a column in my summary worksheet.

I have found the following formula, which looks up a worksheet and takes the total, then I can paste this down to look up the row, essentially transposing row H1 to AG1 to column B on my summary worksheet.

```
=INDEX('201510'!$H$1:$AG$1,ROWS(B$1:B1))
```

Now I want to replace the direct ref to the worksheet tab to a lookup. So when I type the worksheet name in say row 2, it will give me the monthly totals.

This formula looks up the tab reference in B2 and displays the contents of H1. Where B2 has the worksheet name.

```
=INDIRECT("'"&$B$2&"'!$H1")
```

However when I copy this formula down the column, H1 does not change to H2. Furthermore, I need it to transpose vertically to I1.

How can I combine the two formulae?

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 0):

You will need to combine the logic of an INDIRECT function with regular Excel referencing. Note that in your final formula, the "'!$H1" is text, meaning Excel doesn't try to compute it until it calculates the value of the cell. ie: it does not compute that what you are typing is a reference, just text.

So, assuming you continue to use the INDIRECT function, you will need to create the address of the final portion dynamically. There are many ways to do this. For example:

```
=INDIRECT("'"&$B$2&"'!H"&ROW()-1)
```

This version takes the string of the sheet name from B2, and then adds on the "'!H" as an additional string, and then takes the row as the current row number of the cell above the cell the formula is in. ie: if this formula is in D2, it will look up H1 on the other sheet. This method relies on your formula being in a consistent position within your sheet - if you insert a row above this one, it will change what ROW() calculates as, thus changing the formula.

Another method would be to reference H1 in a way that consistently points there, and also iterates into higher numbers as you drag down the formula. This method may be more useful for your purposes, as it also teaches another function:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(H1),COLUMN(H1),,1,$B$2))
```

Note that the ADDRESS function creates a string which shows the way a direct reference to a specific cell would. with the arguments I have above, it picks up the row number of H1 [iterating down, as there are no $ in front of the 1], the column number of H1 [iterating to the right, as there is no $ in front of the H], and the sheet name from $B$2.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it really helps.  And works, to a degree.  However as I drag the formula down, it is iterating H1 down as well, while I want it to look across the row (the INDEX part of the question). So you have improved on the INDIRECT function, but still I have the problem of 'transposing' across the row (as the INDEX function achieves) as the formula is copied down a column. Does that make sense?

Comment: @yesmaybe You need to show your data in your question, and then add a comment @'ing me so I can see the changes. You are not very clear on what you want this to do.

Comment: Grade 'Eh' Bacon I am not sure how to cc on this online forum. The worksheet I am referencing has column totals in H1, through AG1. In my summary page, cell B2 looks up the worksheet name and then B3 looks up H1, B4 = I1, etc, giving the monthly totals in a column down the page. Cell C2 will reference the next month worksheet, and so on.

Comment: @yesmaybe If I understand correctly, my edited formula should now work - as you drag the formula to the right, it will pick up new columns to the right, and as you drag down, it will pick up new rows below.

Comment: @ Grade 'Eh' Bacon I think the easiest way to explain it is to type 1,2,3 and so on in cells H1, I1, J1, and so on.  Then in cell B3 enter this formula =INDEX($H$1:$AG$1,ROWS(B$1:B1)) and drag it down to cell B4, B5, etc.  You will see that the first row is transposed into column B. Now combine that with your INDIRECT formula so it's looking at row H1:AG1 in another worksheet.